# Pythagorean quintuple $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=u^2$ has infinite solutions. Is it difficult to find the general formula of its integer solution?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Pythagorean quintuple equation $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=u^2$ has the infinite set of integer solutions, but it seems that no general solution formula has been published. There are methods to give more solutions, but is there a general formula for the solution? If we consider the Pythagorean multi-tuple equation, $x_ 1^2 + x_ 2^2 + \cdots + x_n ^ 2={x ^ 2} $, what is the maximum value of n, then we can find the general formula of its integer solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a known generalization of the Pythagorean triples valid for $n\ge2$. This is for your five unknowns $x,y,z,w,u$ the following identity with four parameters:
$$(r^2+s^2+t^2+w^2)^2=(w^2-r^2-s^2-t^2)^2+(2rw)^2+(2sw)^2+(2tw)^2$$

Comment: Thank you for giving the formula of the solution, although I'm not sure whether this formula includes all the solutions.

Comment: In combination with this result, this answer should generate all PTs.

Anthony Overmars,  Lorenzo Ntogramatzidis,  Sitalakshmi Venkatraman. A new approach to generate all Pythagorean triples[J]. AIMS Mathematics, 2019, 4(2): 242-253. doi: 10.3934/math.2019.2.242

Comment: @X. D. Dongfang : you do have $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2\right)^2=\left(x_n^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(2x_ix_n)^2$$ where the $x_i$ are arbitrary parameters (**not your unknowns $x_i$ to which you can note here as $X_i$ for example**)

Comment: @X.D. Dongfang: It is clear that there is a typo with the negative sign. The correct formula is $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2\right)^2=\left(x_n^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2\right)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(2x_ix_n)^2$$ so you have $X^2=X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2$

Comment: @Piquito Thank you so much. After reading the equation you wrote earlier, I thought of the equation you are writing now. This should be the total solution. I was thinking that you should also have a lot of exploration on the preliminary proof of Fermat's final problem.

Comment: @X.D. Dongfang: What you say about "a lot of exploration", is true. I am an old man whose youth was dedicated to the search for this demonstration, it was my best dream and my french doctorate in maths  deals on elliptic curves with this goal (I guess you do the same about FLT). Greetings.

Comment: @Piquito: I salute you. I also entered my twilight years. When I was young, I put forward the unitary principle to find the elementary proof of FLT. I know some academicians and university professors, but they are really selfish and even immoral. Academic journals never publish my breakthrough principles and breakthrough papers, and I am often slandered by professional scholars. I was forced to publish about 20% of my research papers on the Internet in the form of We Media Journals (https://www.researchgate.net/profile/X-D-Dongfang/publications).

Comment: @X.D. Dongfang: Dear friend, I have known people that are perfect examples of what you say,the world of "resume builders" is full of those immoral. But, fortunately, also I have known great mathematicians very kind, extremely generous. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito: Dear sir, I'm glad that you have the honor to meet those kind, generous and wise great mathematicians. I wonder if you can provide their information. I still want to write an elementary proof of FLT, which requires a new principle and a new mathematical theorem. Maybe I'm not right. But new principles and new theorems are absolutely beneficial. This is the real significance of studying mathematical problems. We may not be able to solve famous problems perfectly, but if we find something unknown from them, it is progress.

Comment: @X.D. Dongfang: Dear friend, I am retired and I was referring to Alexander Grothendieck (almost a mystic) and Laurent Schwartz (very righteous), both deceased; I also referred to Jean Pierre Serre (whom I did not know personally, but I am aware of his generosity by letter received in response to one of my results). All three are great mathematicians, but I cannot accede to your request for obvious reasons that I hope you understand.Best regards.

Comment: @Piquito: Dear Piquito, I understand your idea, and I do not force others to accept my papers published on the Internet, but I will try to write my own findings. I'm thinking about your formula:
${\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} = {\left( {x_n^2 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {2{x_i}{x_n}} \right)}^2}}$

Comment: It should be : ${\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {x_i^2} } \right)^2} = {\left( {x_n^2 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {2{x_i}{x_n}} \right)}^2}} $

Comment: @X.D. Dongfang: You are right, dear friend. Clearly it was a typo (applying to the Pythagorean triples, it is evident). Thanks you.

Comment: @Piquito: You should publish your formula. Your formula shows the fact that for some Diophantine equations, it may not be possible to find solutions by traditional methods, but we can get inspiration from solutions of similar equations and directly write general solutions. Is there any similarity in Fermat's final question, so that we can find the proof that is easy to understand and can accept the popular test?

Comment: Jean Pierre Serre (born on September 15, 19262 in Bages, east of the Pyrenees) is a French mathematician and is considered one of the greatest mathematicians of the 20th century. He has won many awards for his research, including the Fields Medal in 1954, Balzan Prize in 1985, CNRS gold medal in 1987, Wolf Mathematics Prize in 2000 and the first Abel Prize winner in 2003.

Comment: @Piquito: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584537/diophantine-equation-x-2y-2z-2-m-2n-2-has-infinite-sol, maybe you can give a better answer to this question.

Comment: @Piquito Where does this formula come from? Its equal sign is somewhat puzzling.
${\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} = {\left( {x_n^2 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {2{x_i}{x_n}} \right)}^2}} $

Comment: @Piquito See 
$n = 3 \Rightarrow {\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} - \left( {{{\left( {x_n^2 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)}^2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {2{x_i}{x_n}} \right)}^2}} } \right) =  - x_3^2\left( {2x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + x_3^2} \right) \ne 0$

Comment: @Piquito 
$n = 4 \Rightarrow {\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} - \left( {{{\left( {x_n^2 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)}^2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {2{x_i}{x_n}} \right)}^2}} } \right) =  - x_4^2\left( {2x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + 2x_3^2 + x_4^2} \right) \ne 0$

Comment: @Piquito
$\begin{gathered}
  n = 5 \Rightarrow {\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)^2} - \left( {{{\left( {x_n^2 - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {x_i^2} } \right)}^2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {{{\left( {2{x_i}{x_n}} \right)}^2}} } \right) =  - x_5^2\left( {2x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + 2x_3^2 + 2x_4^2 + x_5^2} \right) \ne 0 \hfill \\
   \vdots  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $