# Diophantine equation ${x ^ 2}+{y ^ 2}+{z ^ 2}={m ^ 2}+{n ^ 2} $ has infinite solutions. What is its general solution formula?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

Diophantine equation ${x ^ 2}+{y ^ 2}+{z ^ 2}={m ^ 2}+{n ^ 2} $ has infinite solutions. For examples,
$\begin{array}{l}
{1^2}+ {3^2} + {4^2}  = {1^2} + {5^2}\\
{1^2} + {2^2} + {6^2} = {4^2} + {5^2}\\
{322^2} + {562^2} + {597^2} = {601^2} + {644^2}\\
{938^2} + {1063^2} + {4722^2} = {536^2} + {4901^2}\\
 \vdots 
\end{array}$

What is its general solution formula? How to get the general solution formula?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141034/discussion-on-question-by-x-d-dongfang-diophantine-equation-x-2y-2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $z\neq 0,$ that means we want all rational solutions to:

$$m^2+n^2-x^2-y^2=1\tag 1$$

We pick one solution, $\mathbf s_0=(m_0,n_0,x_0,y_0)=(-1,0,0,0)$ and any directional vector $\mathbf p=(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$ with the $p_i$ integers with $\gcd(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)=1.$

Then $\mathbf s_0+t\mathbf p$ yields a solution for $t=0$ trivially, and we get another value $t$ where you get another solution.

Specifically, you want $$(-1+p_1t)^2+(p_2t)^2-(p_3t)^2-(p_4t)^2=1$$ which, when simplified and factoring out $t,$ gives you:

$$-2p_1+(p_1^2+p_2^2-p_3^2-p_4^2)t=0\\
t=\frac{2p_1}{p_1^2+p_2^2-p_3^2-p_4^2}$$ where now we assume $p_1^2+p_2^2\neq p_3^2+p_4^2.$

Then our integer solution formula is $$\begin{align}m&=p_1^2-p_2^2+p_3^2+p_4^2\\
n&=2p_1p_2\\
x&=2p_1p_3\\
y&=2p_1p_4\\
z&=p_1^2+p_2^2-p_3^2-p_4^2.
\end{align}$$

This won't give primitive solutions, in that we won't always have $\gcd(m,n,x,y,z)=1,$ but we'll get one from every equivalence class of solutions with $z\neq 0.$

This will also give solutions with $z=0,$ but we don't know yet if it will give all (equivalence classes) of solutions for $z=0.$ But we can show if $z=0,$ the above solution is a scalar multiple of $(m,n,x,y,z)=(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,0),$ which gives all solutions.

The fact that three of the numbers are even makes it clear that we can't get all the primitive solutions with $z\neq 0.$ For example, we can get values $m$ odd, so we should be able to get $n$ odd.

---

For example, $(p_i)=(2,1,1,1)$ gives a solution $(m,n,x,y,z)=(5,4,4,4,3).$

This means we need a solution with $(m,n)$ switched, and possibly scaled .

The corresponding rational solution to $(1)$ is $(m,n,x,y)=(\frac43,\frac53,\frac43,\frac43)$ which is in the direction $p=(7,5,4,4)$ from $s_0.$

That gives $m=56, n=70, x=56,y=56, z=42.$ And that is $14$ times our goal $(m,n,x,y,z)=(4,5,4,4,3).$

---

This technique works for all homogenous quadratic Diophantine equations: once you find one non-zero solution, you can find an infinite class. But the formula won't general **all** solutions - it will only generate all solutions of the corresponding rational equation, which means it will generate all solutions modulo scalar multiplication, and with one fixed variable chosen to be non-zero.

In general, we would first assume $z\neq 0,$ apply the above technique, then assume $z=0$ and solve the resulting smaller Diophantine equation using the same technique. But often, the resulting formula for $z\neq 0$ would give (up to equivalence) all solutions for $z=0.$

Sometimes, we get an obvious variable to assume non-zero. $x^2+xy+y^2=z^2$ has only the trivial solution when $z=0,$ so we can assume $z\neq 0$ for all others.

Comment: ${\left( {p_1^2 + p_2^2 - p_3^2 - p_4^2} \right)^2} + {\left( {2{p_1}{p_3}} \right)^2} + {\left( {2{p_1}{p_4}} \right)^2} = {\left( {p_1^2 - p_2^2 + p_3^2 + p_4^2} \right)^2} + {\left( {2{p_1}{p_2}} \right)^2}$ . It's really clever. It should be able to express all the solutions.

Comment: @X.D.Dongfang Depends on what you mean by "all" in "all solutions."

Comment: Thanks so much.  I see what you mean: this formula contains enough solutions, but whether some solutions are missing or not needs to be proved.

Comment: @X.D.Dongfang No, that's not what I mean. The parameterization doesn't output $(m,n,x,y,z)=(7,1,4,3,5),$ because the parameterization always gives $x,y$ even. But the parameterization will give some multiple $(7k,k,4k,3k,5k).$ Mathematicians tend to treat such multiples as equivalent, so the parameterization gives "all" solutions in the sense that you get at least one solution for all equivalent sets of solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your patience in giving enough explanations. My main interest is to establish correct macro quantum theory and realize the unity of correct micro quantum theory and macro quantum theory. There are some analyses that need to deal with some solutions of Diophantine equations. So, I only pay more attention to the problem of whether the equation has a solution and what the minimum solution is. Your statement is rigorous. Mathematical rigor will change the world of theoretical physics. I suggest mathematicians participate in the research of theoretical physics.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a practical method of getting solutions to the equation $m^2 +n^2= x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. No claim is made here that it is a general solution or that it works all the time. That has yet to be proven (and I don't think I can do that).
We start with decomposing a square, odd or even doesn't matter as the method seems to work for both.
I will just provide few examples to show the procedure.

**Exemple 1:** $81=9^2=(4+5)^2=4^2 + 2*4*5 + 5^2= 4^2 + 40 + 5^2$. It's clear that if we add $3^2$ to both sides we will end up with a solution:
$9^2 + 3^2 = 4^2 + 5^2 + 7^2$.

**Example 2:** $121 = 11^2 = (5+6)^2 =5^2 + 2*5*6 + 6^2= 5^2 + 60 + 6^2$. It's clear that if we add 4 to both sides, we will end up with a solution:
$11^2 +2^2 = 5^2 + 6^2 +8^2$

**Example 3:** $196=14^2 = (6+8)^2 = 6^2 +2*6*8 + 8^2= 6^2 + 96 + 8^2$.
Here too it's clear that if we add $2^2$ to both sides we get a solution.
$14^2 +2^2 = 6^2 + 8^2 + 10^2$.

**Example 4:** $324 = 18^2 = (8 + 10)^2 = 8^2 +2*8*10 + 10^2= 8^2 + 160 + 10^2$.
Adding $3^2$ to both sides we get:
$18^2 +3^2 = 8^2 +10^2 + 13^2$.

I hope that this method can be shown to work in general. There are in fact more ways to test the method since an odd square $n^2$ can be written as:
$n^2= (1 +(n-1))^2 = (2 +(n-2))^2=...= [(n-1)/2 + (n+1)/2]^2$. The same can be done with even squares by using even numbers like:
$14^2 = (6+8)^2 = (4+10)^2 = (2 + 12)^2$.

**Edit #1** There can be more than one solution starting with a given square. Let's look at $18^2$ again.
$18^2 = (6+12)^2 = 6^2 + 2*6*12 + 12^2$. In this case $2*6*12=144=12^2$. So we need to add a square to $12^2$ to get a different square. $5^2$ added to both sides is the solution.
$18^2 + 5^2 = 6^2 +12^2 + 13^2$.

$18^2 = (4+14)^2 = 4^2 + 2*4*14 + 14^2 = 4^2 + 112 + 14^2$ so adding $3^2$ gives:
$18^2 + 3^2 = 4^2 +(112 + 9) + 14^2 = 4^2 + 11^2 + 14^2$.
Note that we have two expressions for $18^2 + 3^2$.
$18^2 + 3^2 = 8^2 + 10^2 + 13^2 = 4^2 + 11^2 + 14^2$.

$18^2 = (2+16)^2 = 2^2 + 2*2*16 +16^2 = 2^2 + 8^2 + 16^2$. In this case we found two squares $6^2$ and $15^2$ which when added (one at a time) to both sides will give:
$18^2 + 6^2 = 2^2 + 10^2 + 16^2$ and
$18^2 + 15^2 = 2^2 + 16^2 + 17^2$

It appears that getting $n^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ can still be transformed into $n^2 + d^2 = a^2 + c^2 + f^2$.

**Edit#2**. In the previous method, it was shown how to solve the equation when starting from a square and its decompositions. Here a method is provided that solves the equation when the starting point is $2ab$ in a square of the form $n^2=(a+b)^2=a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ as long as $2ab=8T_{k}$ with $T_{k}$ the $kth$ triangular number. It is well known that $8T_{k} + 1 = m^2$ so in this case we only need to add $1^2$ to both sides to solve the equation.
The following example will show the procedure.
Let's take $T_{k}=15$ so $8T_{k}=8*15=120=11^2-1$. Now we consider the different ways of writing $8*15$.
$8*15=2*4*15=2*2*30=2*6*10=2*3*20$. In this case we get the following values for $(a,b)=(4,15)=(2,30)=(6,10)=(3,20)$. Now we can setup the equation for every case. Only one example with be shown since the procedure is the same.

$n^2=19^2=(4+15)^2= 4^2 + 2*4*15 + 15^2 = 4^2 + 120 + 15^2$. It's clear to see that adding $1^2$ to both sides to get the solution.
$19^2 + 1^2 = 4^2 + 11^2 + 15^2$.

Once a square is identified, its decomposition into different sum of squares can be generated. This method provides a solution for an infinite number of equations involving triangular numbers through $8T_{k} + 1 = m^2$.

Comment: Any solution is welcome. The world is so big that there are always different solutions to the same problem. This is amazing!

Comment: ${18^2} + {3^2} = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{8^2} + {10^2} + {13^2}\\
{4^2} + {11^2} + {14^2}
\end{array} \right.$
This kind of solution is also very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that there are infinitely many solutions (see my comment above). We know that the identity $$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2=(a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2)^2+(2ab)^2+(2ac)^2+(2ad)^2$$ gives all the solutions of $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=u^2$.

Now we have $$x^2+y^2+z^2=m^2+n^2\iff x^2+y^2+z^2+(im)^2=n^2$$ because the identity is valid in the ring of the Gaussian integers, so for the parameters $a,b,c,id$ we get $$(a^2+b^2+c^2-d^2)^2=(a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2)^2+(2ab)^2+(2ac)^2-(2ad)^2$$ so we have
$$\boxed{(a^2+b^2+c^2-d^2)^2+(2ad)^2=(a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2)^2+(2ab)^2+(2ac)^2}$$ This new identity giving consequently all the solutions of the proposed equation.

Comment: You solved the problem with imaginary numbers. It's amazing. The imaginary number is a good tool, and it is widely used in quantum mechanics. But some physicists claim that imaginary numbers are indispensable in quantum mechanics. This is obviously incorrect. Theoretical physics needs mathematicians to devote themselves to rewriting.

Comment: X.D. Dongfang: Imaginary numbers have nothing of imaginary; they are complex numbers. They were imaginary to the same title that $\sqrt 2$ was irrational (at times when this number was "contrary to the reason" because the knowlege just has a bit more than the natural integers. Regards.

Comment: You are right. There is a new Diophantine question, maybe you can give a good answer. Thank you very much. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587572/how-many-solutions-to-this-diophantine-equation-group-of-com-quantum-theory-doe

Answer (score -2):

A very simple equation. You can write various combinations.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1055645_quadratic_diophantine_equation

For the equation:

$$X_1^2+X_2^2=Y_1^2+Y_2^2+Y_3^2$$

Solutions have the form:

$$X_1=t^2+2(p+s-k)t+2k^2+2p^2+4ps-4pk-2sk$$

$$X_2=t^2+2(p+s-k)t+2k^2+2s^2+4ps-2pk-4sk$$

$$Y_1=t^2+2(p+s-k)t+2k^2+2ps-2pk-2sk$$

$$Y_2=t^2+2(p+s-k)t+2ps$$

$$Y_3=2(p+s-k)(t+p+s-k)$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141036/discussion-on-answer-by-individ-diophantine-equation-x-2y-2z-2m).