# How many solutions to this Diophantine equation group of Com Quantum Theory? Does it have a general solution method?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, linear-diophantine-equations

$\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{{x_1} + 2{x_2} + {2^2}{x_3} + {2^3}{x_4} + {2^4}{x_5}}}{{2\left( {{x_6} + 2{x_7} + {2^2}{x_8} + {2^3}{x_9} + {2^4}} \right)}} = \frac{{1034}}{{1625}} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{x_1} + 3{x_2} + {3^2}{x_3} + {3^3}{x_4} + {3^4}{x_5}}}{{3\left( {{x_6} + 3{x_7} + {3^2}{x_8} + {3^3}{x_9} + {3^4}} \right)}} = \frac{{1975}}{{4522}} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{x_1} + 4{x_2} + {4^2}{x_3} + {4^3}{x_4} + {4^4}{x_5}}}{{4\left( {{x_6} + 4{x_7} + {4^2}{x_8} + {4^3}{x_9} + {4^4}} \right)}} = \frac{{323}}{{966}} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{x_1} + 5{x_2} + {5^2}{x_3} + {5^3}{x_4} + {5^4}{x_5}}}{{5\left( {{x_6} + 5{x_7} + {5^2}{x_8} + {5^3}{x_9} + {5^4}} \right)}} = \frac{{26887}}{{99000}} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{x_1} + 6{x_2} + {6^2}{x_3} + {6^3}{x_4} + {6^4}{x_5}}}{{6\left( {{x_6} + 6{x_7} + {6^2}{x_8} + {6^3}{x_9} + {6^4}} \right)}} = \frac{{2676}}{{11687}} \hfill \\
\end{gathered} $

This Diophantine equation group is derived from the [Com Quantum Law](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353235069_Dongfang_Com_Quantum_Equations_of_LIGO_Signal) fitting of the GW150914 signal of LIGO and it has a set of solutions called the least rational solution,

$\begin{gathered}
  {x_1} = \frac{{63}}{{16}},\quad {x_2} = \frac{{447}}{{32}},\quad {x_3} = \frac{{69}}{4},\quad  \hfill \\
  {x_4} = \frac{{69}}{8},\quad {x_5} = \frac{3}{2},\quad {x_6} = \frac{{105}}{{32}},\quad  \hfill \\
  {x_7} = \frac{{389}}{{32}},\quad {x_8} = \frac{{227}}{{16}},\quad {x_9} = \frac{{13}}{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

This is a group solution found by computer. So do the equations have other rational solutions? Different solutions correspond to the same [Com Quantum Law](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353235069_Dongfang_Com_Quantum_Equations_of_LIGO_Signal). It may take several months for experts in the field of non number theory and computer science to find the above set of solutions. So, is there a general solution method for such Diophantine equations?

Comment: @DS Note that the denominators have a constant term, so the equations are not homogeneous. Scaling all the variable values does not give another solution. Of course you could make it homogenous by introducing an extra variable to stand for the common denominator of the other variables, and then you would get proper Diophantine equation where the solutions are supposed to be integers. Strictly speaking, the given equations are not really Diophantine because they are looking for rational solutions.

Comment: How to obtain the second set of solutions? This once let me rack my brains, but finally I had to give up.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis sorry, I actually didn't notice that

Comment: To summarize the discussions; clearing denominators yields a system of 5 linear equations in 9 variables with integral coefficients. Parametrizing all solutions is a trivial matter to any first-year student in mathematics. Finding 'small' solutions is also not difficult, but depends on your definition of ' small' . It is certainly difficult to believe that this has taken much effort for any expert in the field to solve.

Comment: The so-called minimum solution means that the number of digits in the numerator and denominator representing the rational number of the solution is as small as possible. Although it is a small matter to solve such problems, even as you said, even primary school students can solve them. The problem is that no one has yet been able to give the second set of solutions. Empty talk is meaningless. We need to give specific solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You can reduce each of your five equations to a linear equation so you get a system of five linear equations with nine  unknowns
$$a_{11}x_1+\cdots a_{19}x_9=c_1\\a_{21}x_1+\cdots a_{29}x_9=c_2\\.......\\a_{51}x_1+\cdots+a_{59}x_9=c_5$$ and this have infinitely many solutions. In fact, you can take arbitrary values, for example, for $x_6,x_7,x_8$ and $x_9$ so you get a system of five equations with five unknowns
$$a_{11}x_1+\cdots a_{15}x_5=A_1\\a_{21}x_1+\cdots a_{25}x_5=A_2\\.......\\a_{51}x_1+\cdots+a_{55}x_5=A_5$$

and for each of such a systems with determinant distinct of zero you have a rational solution for each value of the resultant $A_i$. If all the determinants (there are $\binom95=126$ in total) are null also you have infinitely many solutions.

**Example**: Make, for example, $x_6=x_7=x_8=x_9=1$ and you will have the system
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1&2a_1&2^2a_1&2^3a_1&2^4a_1\\a_2&3a_2&3^2a_2&3^3a_2&3^4a_2\\a_3&4a_3&4^2a_3&4^3a_3&4^4a_3\\a_4&5a_4&5^2a_4&5^3a_4&5^4a_4\\a_5&6a_5&6^2a_5&6^3a_5&6^4a_5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A_1\\A_2\\A_3\\A_4\\A_5\end{pmatrix}$$ where $A_1=2a_1(2^5-1), A_2=\dfrac{3a_2(3^5-1)}{2},A_3=\dfrac{4a_3(4^5-1)}{3},A_4=\dfrac{5a_4(5^5-1)}{4}$ and $A_5=\dfrac{6a_5(6^5-1)}{5}$

If the determinant is non-zero there is a unique solution according when $x_6,x_7,x_8$ and $x_9$ are all equal to $1$ as we have chosen but you can vary these arbitrarily and you get infinitely many solutions.

And if the determinant is null, a fortiori you have infinitely many solutions, for example the system $$2x+3y=1\\4x+6y=2$$ has determinant zero but it is the equation of a rightline $2x+3y=1$ which have an infinity of points as you know.

Comment: However, the left side is a fraction, which cannot be solved in this way.

Comment: $$\dfrac XY=\dfrac ab\iff bX=aY\iff bX-aY=0$$

Comment: It is difficult to prove whether there are other solutions. In China, a few computer experts have tried.

Comment: I answer to your last comment editing with an example my answer above. You are risking to be downvoted if you follow with negative argument. Chine is a great country and its computer experts cannot deny as yourself do.

Comment: The formula you just edited seems to show some hope. Appreciate that you can always find new ways. Another set of solutions is the most illustrative. Looking forward to your results.
It seems that you have misunderstood the previous comments. You are pursuing the development of mathematical theory and its application and mathematical methods. I am pursuing the results of physical application. I do not mean to deny, but hope to get a new set of solutions.

Comment: @X. D. Dongfanf: In my answers there is NOTHING of new, all is elementary linear algebra known enough for begineers mathematicians. Regards.

Comment: Let me ask a question. Can we get another set of solutions to the above fractional Diophantine equations? What are the specific values?

Comment: If you make $x_6=...=x_9=0$ then the answer is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%2B2*b%2B2%5E2*c%2B2%5E3*d%2B2%5E4*e+%3D2%5E5*1034%2F1625%2C+a%2B3*b%2B3%5E2*c%2B3%5E3*d%2B3%5E4*e+%3D3%5E5*1975%2F4522%2C+a%2B4*b%2B4%5E2*c%2B4%5E3*d%2B4%5E4*e+%3D4%5E5*323%2F966%2C+a%2B5*b%2B5%5E2*c%2B5%5E3*d%2B5%5E4*e+%3D5%5E5*26887%2F99000%2C+a%2B6*b%2B6%5E2*c%2B6%5E3*d%2B6%5E4*e+%3D6%5E5*2676%2F11687), and ...

Comment: ... if you set $x_6=...=x_9=1$ you get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%2B2*b%2B2%5E2*c%2B2%5E3*d%2B2%5E4*e%3D62*1034%2F1625%2C+a%2B3*b%2B3%5E2*c%2B3%5E3*d%2B3%5E4*e%3D363*1975%2F4522%2C+a%2B4*b%2B4%5E2*c%2B4%5E3*d%2B4%5E4*e%3D1364*323%2F966%2C+a%2B5*b%2B5%5E2*c%2B5%5E3*d%2B5%5E4*e%3D3905*26887%2F99000%2C+a%2B6*b%2B6%5E2*c%2B6%5E3*d%2B6%5E4*e%3D9330*2676%2F11687). Those fractions have numbers of 11 to 14 digits, much longer than the given solution. The problem lies not in finding solutions, but in finding small ones.

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Piquito. I recently rewrote the article "Brief General Solutions to Congruence Equations" to refocus on the minimum solution - to be precise, the minimum digit solution. Thank you for providing a good answer. I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the minimum digit solution given in the problem using a computer? Looking forward to your further answers. Thank you!
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353355373_Brief_General_Solutions_to_Congruence_Equations

Answer (score 1):

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9)$=

`(5854/27, 3523/81, 133/81, 3589/81, 124/81, 16115/81, 422/81, 1423/81, 2491/81)`

`(11789/36, 33973/216, 25513/216, 20483/72, 31/18, 73265/216, 1301/108, 10207/54, 41861/216)`

`(167/27, 29563/648, 6211/1296, 2441/324, 653/432, 610/81, 46483/1296, 613/162, 7709/1296)`

`(306/5, 93381/125, 62806/125, 2096/125, 181/125, 747/25, 87133/125, 43624/125, 1391/125)`

`(19704/625, 11122/625, 9517/625, 8281/625, 188/125, 716/25, 1407/125, 9141/625, 6027/625)`

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Dmitry Ezhov. I have copied the solutions you provided. These solutions are obviously more ideal than other solutions. But I want to know why the solution given in the question cannot be included in your solution? If you have a systematic solution method to the above indefinite equations, could you write a paper in response to the questions raised in the last section of recently rewritten article? Thank you. Refer to: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353355373_Brief_General_Solutions_to_Congruence_Equations

Comment: @X.D.Dongfang, your solution for fixed denominator `32`, other solutions for denominators `81,216,1296,125,625`. It is linear optimization problem with constraints (MILP).

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to you publishing your systematic solution in the appropriate place.